# writing an mp3 player in c#, use dictionary or array for metadata?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, mp3

i'm writing an mp3 player in c#, and i'm wondering how to store the metadata for quick retrieval.  here's the data i need to store for each individual file:

- file location
- file name
- artist
- album
- track title
- album artwork

how should i store the data?  dictionary of arrays?  dictionary of dictionaries? i want to populate a listbox with individual entries, so if i have a button that says artist, it will quickly get the artist info, put it in an array and populate the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)?

```
// define song object.
public class Song 
{
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string TrackTitle { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtwork { get; set; }
}

// create list of songs.
List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();

// add new song to list.
songs.Add(new Song {
        FileLocation = "/filepath/sade.mp3",
        FileName = "Sade", 
        Artist = "Sade", 
        Album = "Sade", 
        TrackTitle = "Smooth Operator", 
        AlbumArtwork "TBD"
});

// access first song in list.
Song song = songs[0];

// access property of song.
string trackTitle = song.TrackTitle;
```

Of course you could break this down into an even more [object-oriented design](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tusharkantagarwal/objectorientedcsharp11162005070743AM/objectorientedcsharp.aspx) by making the song properties complex objects as well.  For example:

```
public class Album
{
    public string Name
    public DateTime ReleaseDate
    public string Artwork { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public string Name
    public List<Album> Albums
}

public class Song 
{
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public string TrackTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And then, for example, access the album properties like this:

```
string firstAlbumName = song.Artist.Albums[0].Name;
```

Comment: would sql be faster to access the metadata, or the list?  i have about <200k songs to access.  it seems that using "list" would be the easier solution, but sql would be the most efficient.  i don't know much about sql, and it would be faster for me to impliment the above class than have to sit and teach myself sql.  decisions, decisions.......

Comment: Well, you should probably use both.  Store all your data in a database.  Then fetch the appropriate data (based on some search criteria) and populate Song objects and list with that data.  Then you can much more easily work with those objects and present them on the front-end as you see fit.

Comment: I covered just the object/model part of the solution and not the database part, because I assumed you were asking how to store your songs in memory (in the short-term), not in the long-term on disk.

Comment: yeah, i understand that part. is there an easy example to read/ write sql from c#? thanks. i'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Check out examples here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx  

I'm also a big fan of the Entity Framework:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: thanks for that.  the second one seems very useful.  is there a "dummies guide to setting up a simple sql database"?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything there that would influence storage, do I would say "a list of classes", i.e. a `List<Track>` or similar, with

```
public class Track {
    public string Path {get;set;}
    ...
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string ArtworkPath {get;set;}
}
```

If the volume is high, you might want to look at databases rather than in-memory storage. SQL Server (Express or Compact) for example, are both free. This may allow for more specialised indexing without much effort, plus pre-built persistence.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store your data is in a database, there are different types a small free database to choose from. For example sqlite is nice. You can use sql for fast access of of the data (searching, grouping, etc).